# Can't remote debug a Python web site in Azure with vs2013

Tags: python, azure, remote-debugging, ptvs

I deployed a bottle website on Azure but it shows 500 (internal error) and I can’t see the log. I refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Azure-Remote-Debugging to debug my project but it failed.
It shows the error message as below.

```
could not attach to python.exe process on Azure web site at testpybottleapp.azurewebsites.net. 
Error retrieving websocket debug proxy information from web.config.
```

And when I try to open http://testpybottleapp.azurewebsites.net/ptvsd it said `ptvsd not existed`.

Comment: To enable remote debug of Azure App Service needs to publish the app in debug mode. Have you published in debug mode? See https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Web-Project#publishing-to-microsoft-azure

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [VorlonJS](http://www.davevoyles.com/creating-and-debugging-hosted-web-apps-with-manifoldjs-and-vorlonjs/) as well? It's a remote website debugger which may help in this case.

Alternatively, could you try grabbing a similar VM from [VMDepot](https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index), uploading that, and seeing if you have the same issue? That could help us troubleshoot and understand if the issue lies in the VM itself, or one of the configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use the remote debug on Azure for python website, we should set the publish mode as "debug". And then we should enable websocket.

Meanwhile I suggest you can try to use the debug=>Attach to Process and input  wss://*WSGI_PTVSD_SECRET*@*WEBSITE_NAME*.azurewebsites.net/ptvsd. When the process (Python.exe) is shown,you can click the "Attach".  Then you can open your website http://*WEBSITE_NAME*.azurewebsites.net in browser.
[image]

If you visit the URL like "http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/ptvsd" and get the "ptvsd not existed" error, Please double check these points:

1. You should publish your website as Debug mode not release mode.
2. Make sure the 'WSGI_PTVSD_SECRET' in local is same as the Azure website .